# Why does 'Azure Kubernetes Service RBAC Reader' role allow deployments write

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-active-directory, azure-aks

The built-in Azure role [Azure Kubernetes Service RBAC Reader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#azure-kubernetes-service-rbac-reader) is described as:

```
Allows read-only access to see most objects in a namespace....
```

Then why does it allow the following action:

```
Microsoft.Resources/deployments/write
```

which is described as

```
Creates or updates an deployment.
```

How is this not a security issue?

Comment: Hello @user3502661, If my answer is helpful for you, you can Upvote and accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is two field you will be able to see if you open Kubernetes Cluster through a portal.

1. Action: This lists all Azure Kubernetes service role.
2. Data Action: This is main that describes about specific role i.e., what are the action you able to perform on data.

[image]

[`Microsoft.Resources`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/resource-provider-operations#microsoftresources)`/deployments/write` this is not belongs to `Azure Kubernetes Service RBAC Reader` Role. If you go to DataAction of RBAC Reader there no writes role. This Action belongs to `Azure Kubernetes Service RBAC Write` Role. See the below Picture.

[image]

Note :
[`Microsoft.Resources`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/resource-provider-operations#microsoftresources) contains `Microsoft.ContainerService/managedCluster/apps` resource as well

[image]

[`Microsoft.Resources`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/resource-provider-operations#microsoftresources)`/deployments/write` it has mention in Action Section not DataAction Section of Azure Kubernetes Service RBAC Reader Role.

Comment: So are you saying the actions listed in the "Action Section" of the [Azure Kubernetes Service RBAC Reader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#azure-kubernetes-service-rbac-reader) documentation don't necessarily apply? I find that a bit confusing.

Comment: @user3502661, Action section is a generic description of all RBAC role . The for specific RBAC role it shows on dataAction.

Comment: I don't buy it. Look at [Azure Kubernetes Service Contributor Role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#azure-kubernetes-service-contributor-role) for example. It has a smaller list under "Actions" and nothing under "DataActions" does that mean this role does nothing?

Comment: @user3502661, There is also list  under dataAction please click on that you can able to see. The list under dataAction describe about specific role that you have selected.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that this permission was added by mistake. See [this Github issue](https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/2416):

> The action "Microsoft.Resources/deployments/write" does not affect the k8s resources. Only data actions affect the k8s resources via Azure RBAC i.e the permissions mentioned in the dataactions field. So it will not affect the Azure RBAC you set for the k8s resources in the cluster. The action "Microsoft.Resources/deployments/write" is usually added for built-in roles.

Two of the answers read,

> [...] I will follow up that internally on removing that action. [...]

and

> [...] we are working to see what "Write" permissions we can remove without breaking things [...]